# Regex replace found item

Tags: c#, regex

I have large text. I need to find an URL and replace the found text with another text.

Here is an example:

```
http://cdn.example.com/content/dev/images/some.png
http://cdn.example.com/content/qa/images/some.png
http://cdn.example.com/content/preprod/images/some.png
```

to

```
http://cdn.example.com/content/qa/images/some.png
http://cdn.example.com/content/preprod/images/some.png
http://cdn.example.com/content/live/images/some.png
```

I need to find url segment and just replace the found segment.
i have the following code:

```
Regex rxCdnReplace = new Regex(@"http://cdn.example.com/content/(\w+)/", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
rxCdnReplace.Replace(str,new MatchEvaluator(CdnRename.ReplaceEvaluator))
```

How can I do this with regex?

Comment: Can't you just use `string.Replace()` for this since you know the exact strings?

Comment: Be careful about the order in which you do your replacements, as some of the desired output text is the same as some of your input text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this regex:

```
(?<=content\/).+(?=\/images)
```

It returns the value between content/ and /images

E.g. for the link `http://cdn.example.com/content/dev/images/some.png`
the regex returns `dev` which you should replace with `qa`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // This is the input string we are replacing parts from.
    string input = "http://cdn.example.com/content/dev/images/some.png";

    // Use Regex.Replace to replace the pattern in the input.
      string output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=content\/).+(?=\/images)", "qa");

    // Write the output.
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you literally mean you need to change occurrences of those particular strings into the ones presented below, you could do something like:

```
str = str.Replace("http://cdn.example.com/content/qa/images/some.png", "http://cdn.example.com/content/preprod/images/some.png")
```

However, I don't think this is what you are after (as you have mentioned regex), so I think you'll need to be more specific on what needs changing.

Comment: You need to do the `Replace()`s in the reverse order, otherwise the replacements made by the first one will be replaced again by the subsequent ones.